# Как в jquery обратиться к потомку объекта по которому кликнули?

Tags: jquery, click

Всем Привет!!!

Есть вот такой HTML код:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <figure class="effect">
            <img src="img"/>
            <figcaption>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur......</p>
                <a href="#">View more</a>
            </figcaption>           
        </figure>
        <figure class="effect">
            <img src="img"/>
            <figcaption>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ......</p>
                <a href="#">View more</a>
            </figcaption>           
        </figure>
        <figure class="effect">
            <img src="img"/>
            <figcaption>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec........</p>
                <a href="#">View more</a>
            </figcaption>           
        </figure>
    </div>
```

Как в jquery можно реализовать следующее:

1. при клике по `<figure class="effect">` у ссылки которая является потомком этого `<figure class="effect">` должен добавиться класс `<active>`;
2. при этом получается, что класс `<active>` должен добавляться только там где кликнули.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.effect').click(function() {
    var wrapper = $('.wrapper').find('.active');
    wrapper.removeClass('active');
    $('a', this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <figure class="effect">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur......</p>
      <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="effect">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ......</p>
      <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="effect">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec........</p>
      <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: "у ссылки ... должен добавиться класс"

Comment: @Igor добавил, благодарю.

Comment: Круто!!! Работает так как хотелось!!! Как оказывается это просто когда понимаешь)))) Огромное спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 1):

В таком духе?

```js
$('figure.effect').on('click', function() {
  $('a', this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <figure class="effect">
    <img src="img" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur......</p>
      <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="effect">
    <img src="img" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ......</p>
      <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="effect">
    <img src="img" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec........</p>
      <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Немного не то. Я хотел что б класс <active> добавлялся только одному элементу при клике, а у остальных удалялся. Но всё-равно спасибо за то, что откликнулись!!!